# Ubuntu not recognising Windows 7 install and drives

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-7

I am trying to dual boot windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.04. I have done a clean install of Windows 7 and the drives are formatted and I have left an unallocated drive for the Ubuntu install.

When I install Ubuntu I don't get the first installation type screen; it goes straight to this one

[image: image 2]

I have tried running fix parts as suggested in previous posts but to no avail.

This is my disk management in Windows 7.

[image: image 3]

What should I do?

Answer (score -2):

The partition layout stirs of something inside of me - I would not recommend the layout with a C-drive on your secondary drive. I cannot provide proof in form of documentation on this - but it's a bit unusual to have this layout.

Also (perhaps more relevant): The free space - does it reside on a logical partition? I think that could be the reason why the installer doesnt show any free space.

You can use Gparted on a USB drive to view the layout in details and maybe move the partition around so that you have free space in the beginning of the disk, which would then show up as available space for a primary partition in the installer :)

Comment: Thanks for this I will try Gparted. However, I have no data to be lost on the windows install would you recommend reinstalling Windows on the primary drive?